# Why do assertion methods work on private class members only when intersecting with public members?

Tags: typescript, type-assertion

I am working with typescript. In my code, I am doing a type check via an assertion method for a private member. After research, It appears that you cannot type guard private class members. For example,

```
class Example {
    private num?: number;

    addToNumber(value: number) {
        this.assertNumberIsSet();
        this.num += value;
    }

    assertNumberIsSet(): asserts this is { num: number } {
        if (typeof this.num !== 'number') {
            throw TypeError('num is undefined');
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, the compiler will give the following error:

> Property 'num' does not exist on type 'never'.
> The intersection 'this & { num: number; }' was reduced to 'never' because property 'num' exists in multiple constituents and is private in some.

However, when intersecting it's public members with "keyof", it works.

```
class Example {
    private num?: number;

    addToNumber(value: number) {
        this.assertNumberIsSet();
        this.num += value;
    }

    assertNumberIsSet(): asserts this is { [key in keyof this]: this[key] } & { num: number } {
        if (typeof this.num !== 'number') {
            throw TypeError('num is undefined');
        }
    }
}
```

Why does this second code example work, but not the first example? And would this be considered a valid solution for type guarding a private member?

Comment: I don't know if the second code example "works", it seems not to explode inside the class body, but outside you get the same undesirable reduction to `never`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w1kl2m).  It probably works because inside the class body, the [`this` type](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) is implicitly generic, so the mapped generic type is confusing the compiler enough to defer evaluation.  The main issue with what you're doing is described in [this github comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49709#issuecomment-1168964154).

Comment: (see prev comment). If I were you I'd give up on this and switch to `protected` (which will not blow up, but *will* expose the property after the assertion if used outside the class body) or refactor entirely, since type guarding `private` properties like this just isn't supported.   Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer post explaining; if not, what am I missing?